# Client connect() failed, server accept() succeeded. Why?

Tags: c++, sockets, mfc

I have a client-server system where simply client should connect to server. Here is what happens when i click Connect on client:

```
BOOL connectionStatus = m_sockClient.Connect(sIpAddr, 27386);
```

this call fails (connectionStatus being 0) and GetLastError returns 10035 (try again)

On the other hand, server accepts the connection! How? like this: Breakpoint on the first line of OnReceive() function of server socket is hit and

```
BOOL receivedConnection = Accept( m_sockRecv );
```

returns true.

1. If connect() attempt failed, why was this Accept() successful? This is what I do not understand.
2. How can I make CAsyncSocket blocking?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [expected behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxt965kz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).  The error is WSAEWOULDBLOCK which means you need to wait for the OnConnect event to know when the connection is completely established.  I'm not sure if there is a way to make it blocking, the whole point of the async wrapper is to make everything non-blocking.  If you want blocking semantics you should probably be using [CSocket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxzt95kb%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).